# Scrape text under <h4> using Requests-HTML (Requests-HTML, Python)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests-html

I am attempting to extract the socket type of the cpu as you can see in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNtZk.png). I have identified that the socket type is under the `<h4>` Socket heading as seen in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2epby.png).

So far I have been able to scrape `.spec.block` and find all `<h4>'s` nested inside. However I can't get the text under each heading

Here is my code

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('https://au.pcpartpicker.com/product/' + jLF48d)
about = r.html.find('.specs.block')[0]
about = about.find('h4')

print(about.text)
```

This prints

```
 [ <Element 'h4' >, <Element 'h4' >, <Element 'h4' >, <Element 'h4' >,
 <Element 'h4' >, <Element 'h4' >, <Element 'h4' >, <Element 'h4' >,
 <Element 'h4' >, <Element 'h4' >, <Element 'h4' >]
```

However when I change the print statement to:

```
print(about.text)
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

**Update:**

```
print(about[0].text)
```

This code prints:

> Manufacturer
>   AMD
>   Which is the first heading and text however I need the 4th

Any idea what code I can use to reach the desired result?

If you require any more information please let me know.

Comment: `about[0].text`

Comment: That returns the first heading and text: Manufacturer
AMD. How can i get the 4th heading and text Socket? Thanks

Comment: fixed about[3].text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing:
    print(about[0].text)

With

```
print(about[3].text)
```

As seen on the code in my question above solved the problem for me!

Comment: You can accept your own answer, if it solved your problem.

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't let me